# How to show only 3 recent applications in Mac's dock

Tags: dock

Even though I run those command, there are many recent app icons on my dock

```
defaults write com.apple.dock show-recents -bool true;
defaults write com.apple.dock show-recent-count -int 3;
killall Dock
```

How to show only up to 3 recent applications in Mac's dock